# Bundle with order numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am  trying to generate a report where I want to get total sale values and quantities .
explanation:
When customers some products they get free gift , so items are two types standard and free gift . When they buy standard item they get free gift but not all the customers are eligible for it. In database they are hard coded as standard =0 and free gift as =1.

Aim 1: I would like to get only number of orders with free gifts and the total of that orders.

Aim 2: I want to count each count of free gift to find out top 10.
All the fields are in brackets.
below is simple example .
Hope this make sense. Thank you .
[image]
Results : [image]

my script:

```
 select
 oh.[order date],
 oh.[order guid],
 [Item No_] as SKU
 ,ti.[Description],
 ol.[quantity],
 ol.Amount,
 [EMS Available Quantity] as Stock_Qty,
 (case when [Product Type]=0 then 'Standard' 
  when[Product Type]=1 then 'free_gift'
 end) as Product_Type
 from [Big$Item] TI
  Inner join [Big$Inventory] I
 ON I.[Item No_] = TI.[No_]
 inner join [Big$Order Line] ol
 on ti.[No_]=ol.[No_]
 inner join [Big$Order header]oh
 on oh.[order guid]=ol.[order guid]
 where [Product Type] in ('0','1') 
 and oh.[order date] between'2017-06-12' and '2017-06-18' 
 order by [order date] asc
```

Comment: could you create a sqlfiddle with the tables and sample data here http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post the link?
whats your current result and whats your desired result exactly?

Comment: Hi, I have given example in my description.

Comment: you posted pictures - so nobody is able to use the data, thats why i give you the hint with sqlfiddle.

your script obviously has differend columns than the pictures show above.

does the "result" show your desired result? thats not clear for me.

if you would post the create table statements, insert statements for sample data and exactly describe your desired result, it will be easier for everybody to help

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee6c4/1

Comment: Hi, there is link to sqlfiddle, script is there, for some reason it is not giving me sql run script. My desired results are want to count total number of free items and total order amount. in my pics explained it clearly.Sorry as i am new tried to explain in pics.

Comment: please any help available.

Comment: thanks for the sqlfiddle - but it just includes one table - 
it's still not clear for me, what you want to do.
what should be the result from your testdata at sqlfiddle?

Comment: i put the your testdata here and tried a query - http://rextester.com/HYJI78406 - could you have a look? is this what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have a solution - maybe not the most beautiful one - but it is working: 
i have also added the create statement and the testdata insert - you can also reproduce it with this test link: http://rextester.com/JRV11837 

The first Select just returns all `orderguid` which have at least one free gift. 
The second Select i used to join includes the total amount of each order. As i use an `INNER JOIN` the final result will be just orders which include freegifts. 
Finally i just group the resultset by the description of the freegift.

```
CREATE TABLE mygifttable
( Date        datetime
 ,orderguid   varchar(10)
 ,description varchar(55)
 ,sku         int
 ,amount      decimal)
;

INSERT INTO mygifttable VALUES
    ('2017-06-01', '1234', 'Sony Speakers'   , 25, 100),
    ('2017-06-01', '1234', 'Sony Tv'         , 23, 250),
    ('2017-06-01', '1234', 'Tv stand'        , 11, 0),

    ('2017-06-01', '1235', 'Samsung Speakers', 28, 150),
    ('2017-06-01', '1235', 'Samsung Tv'      , 26, 350),
    ('2017-06-01', '1235', 'Wall mount'      , 10, 0),

    ('2017-06-01', '1236', 'Sony Speakers'   , 25, 100),
    ('2017-06-01', '1236', 'Sony Tv'         , 23, 250),
    ('2017-06-01', '1236', 'Tv stand'        , 11, 0),

    ('2017-06-01', '1237', 'Apple mobiles'   , 29, 900),
    ('2017-06-01', '1237', 'Apple cable'     , 30, 800)
;

SELECT freegifttable.description
      ,SUM(freegifttable.freegift) as Free_Gifts
      ,SUM(totalamount.orderamount) as Total_Orderamount
  FROM (
         SELECT description
               ,orderguid
               ,SUM(IIF(amount = 0, 1,0)) as freegift
           FROM mygifttable
          GROUP BY description, orderguid
         HAVING SUM(IIF(amount = 0, 1,0)) != 0
       ) freegifttable
 INNER JOIN 
       (
           SELECT orderguid
                 ,SUM(amount) as orderamount
             FROM mygifttable
            GROUP BY orderguid      
        ) totalamount
    ON totalamount.orderguid = freegifttable.orderguid  
 GROUP BY freegifttable.description
 ;
```

Comment: Hi, it is giving errors on these lines    SUM(IIF(amount = 0, 1,0)) as freegift               and SUM(IIF(amount = 0, 1,0)) != 0 as I am using sql2012 is this the case??

Comment: Whats the exact error message? Did you check the rextester link i added? works fine there

Comment: yes true , I have checked , it working  perfect there ,but when I put that on to SQL the following error coming up                                               
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near 'totalamount'.